# Mounting an encrypted filesystem from the terminal

Tags: encryption

I have a USB-OTG device with an encrypted LUKS filesystem. Typically, on Linux you just run `cryptsetup luksOpen ...` to open up the device.

On Android 4.4.4 (CyanogenMod 11M9), how can I unlock an encrypted filesystem? I know this is possible because the encryption option provided by the OS uses dm-crypt/LUKS.